Bayesian Optimization using randomForest surrogate model in R language is taking a very longer time to complete
I am running a Bayesian Optimization to optimize an objective function where the difference between the predicted validation set and the mean of initial output of the dataset is kept to the bearest minimum; however, it is taking a very longtime to finished. It is getting to about 24hrs, yet still running. Now, I am running the same code in another environment and I have drastically reduced the ranges of the hyperparameters, and also reduced the dimensions of the training set through feature selection, yet it is almost getting to an hour. Below are the description of the codes for the two cases, and I hope someone can kindly help me:
**1st CASE**; Time:18hrs, still running; Dimiensions:29 features; Sample size; 4000

#Define Objective Function
optimization_objective <- function(ntree,mtry,nodesize) {
  
  # Train random forest model with specified hyperparameters
  model <- randomForest(y_train ~ ., data = X_train, ntree = ntree, mtry = mtry, nodesize = nodesize)
  

  # Make predictions on training set
  predictions <- predict(model, X_test)

  # Calculate mean absolute error between predictions and output_mean
  error <- mean(abs(predictions - output_mean))
  
  # Return the negative of the error as the score
  return(-error)
}

# Define search space for Bayesian Optimization
bounds <- list(
  ntree = c(100, 1000),    # Range for number of trees
  mtry = c(1, ncol(X_train)),  # Range for number of variables to sample
  nodesize = c(1, 100)     # Range for minimum node size
)

# Perform Bayesian Optimization
opt_result <- BayesianOptimization(optimization_objective, 
                                   bounds = bounds, 
                                   init_points = 5, 
                                   n_iter = 10)


**2nd CASE**; Time:1hr, still running; Dimiensions:4 features; Sample size; 400


#Define Objective Function
optimization_objective <- function(ntree,mtry,nodesize) {
  
# Extract hyperparameters from params
  
# Train random forest model with specified hyperparameters
  model <- randomForest(y_train ~ ., data = X_train, ntree = ntree, mtry = mtry, nodesize = nodesize)
  
 # Make predictions on training set
  predictions <- predict(model, newdata = X_train)
  
  >Calculate mean absolute error between predictions and output_mean
  error <- mean(abs(predictions - output_mean))
  
  # Return the negative of the error as the score
  return(-error)
}

# Define search space for Bayesian Optimization
bounds <- list(
  ntree = c(10, 50),    # Range for number of trees
  mtry = c(1, ncol(X_train)),  # Range for number of variables to sample
  nodesize = c(1, 10)     # Range for minimum node size
)

# Perform Bayesian Optimization
opt_result <- BayesianOptimization(optimization_objective, 
                                   bounds = bounds, 
                                   init_points = 5, 
                                   n_iter = 2)

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

GP-based BO is just really slow. We're working on it, I promise :) If you are comfortable with Python, I'd recommend TuRBO.

In order to get close to optimum, you could consider a grid search using caret in R.  What package provided the BayesianOptimization function?  It is good to show that in your code, either through package::function, or require(package).  How long does a single run of the randomForest take outside of the BayesianOptimization?

Hi John Madden. Actually, I have not even tried GP-based. It was with Random Foest, and it is slow.

Hi, R Carnell. I installed the library using install. packages ("BayesianOptimization") and I load the library using library (BayesianOptimization) . Outside of BayesianOptimization, the single run of randomForest model traninig and validation is within 20-30secs or even less.
